# Javascript "SCRIPT5: Access is denied" opening PDF from script

Tags: javascript, access-denied

I've read many other posted questions on SO and so far have found nothing to help me solve my problem.

We have a web form that runs on our LAN opening up PDF files in Javascript using the OPEN function.

For the longest time there have been no problems.

Today two of the four users reported that the form was not opening the PDF file anymore.

The other two users are not experiencing any problems.

I now get the same problem on my work machine and home machines (through the VPN), both win7 64 boxes, when trying to use the same web form. The users with the problem have a winXP box and a win7 pro box respectively.

The users with no issues have winXP boxes, for whatever this OS information is worth.

The following Javascript returns *SCRIPT5: Access is denied.* in IE9 and *Access is denied* opening file from script in Firefox or Chrome.

```
var path = 'file://server1//Temp/file.pdf';

var newWin;

if(path != '') {
    newWin = open(path,'pdf');
}
```

I'm at my wits end. What is going on here?? I have frustrated users waiting in the morning, any help?? =)

Comment: Is an UNC path to network share in your network: `\\server1\temp`?

Comment: Yes Andrew, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for IE:

On client IE browser do next:

1. in IE open `Internet Options` dialog
2. Go to `Security Tab`
3. Select `Local intranet` icon and click on `Sites` button. In IE9 click `Advanced` button.
4. Add into list address of web-server from you load a page with code in Question (example: `http://intranetHttpServer`).